# arcs donut chart with CAShapelayer - border of underlaying layers are visible

Tags: ios, calayer, cashapelayer

I draw a donut chart with CAShapeLayers arcs. I draw it[image] by putting one on top of another and the problem that underneath layers edges are visible.

code of drawing is following

```
for (index, item) in values.enumerated() {
            var currentValue = previousValue + item.value
            previousValue = currentValue
            if index == values.count - 1 {
                currentValue = 100
            }

            let layer = CAShapeLayer()
            let path = UIBezierPath()

            let separatorLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            let separatorPath = UIBezierPath()

            let radius: CGFloat = self.frame.width / 2 - lineWidth / 2
            let center: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width / 2, y: self.bounds.width / 2)

            separatorPath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: percentToRadians(percent: -25), endAngle: percentToRadians(percent: CGFloat(currentValue - 25 + 0.2)), clockwise: true)
            separatorLayer.path = separatorPath.cgPath
            separatorLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            separatorLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            separatorLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
            separatorLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
            self.layer.addSublayer(separatorLayer)
            separatorLayer.add(createGraphAnimation(), forKey: nil)
            separatorLayer.zPosition = -(CGFloat)(index)

            path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: percentToRadians(percent: -25), endAngle: percentToRadians(percent: CGFloat(currentValue - 25)), clockwise: true)
            layer.path = path.cgPath
            layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            layer.strokeColor = item.color.cgColor
            layer.lineWidth = lineWidth
            layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
            layer.shouldRasterize = true
            layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
            layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true
            separatorLayer.addSublayer(layer)
            layer.add(createGraphAnimation(), forKey: nil)
            layer.zPosition = -(CGFloat)(index)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

UPD

Tried code

```
let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2)
        mask.fillColor = nil
        mask.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        mask.lineWidth = lineWidth * 2
        let maskPath = CGMutablePath()
        maskPath.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: self.radius, y: self.radius), radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true)
        maskPath.closeSubpath()
        mask.path = maskPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
```

but it masks only inner edges, outer still has fringe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fringe you're seeing happens because you're drawing exactly the same shape in the same position twice, and alpha compositing (as commonly implemented) is not designed to handle that. [Porter and Duff's paper, “Compositing Digital Images”](https://keithp.com/~keithp/porterduff/p253-porter.pdf), which introduced alpha compositing, discusses the problem:

> We must remember that our basic assumption about the
>   division of subpixel areas by geometric objects breaks
>   down in the face of input pictures with correlated mattes.
>   When one picture appears twice in a compositing expression,
>   we must take care with our computations of F A and
>   F B. Those listed in the table are correct only for uncorrelated
>   pictures.

When it says “matte”, it basically means transparency. When it says “uncorrelated pictures”, it means two pictures whose transparent areas have no special relationship. But in your case, your two pictures do have a special relationship: the pictures are transparent in exactly the same areas!

Here's a self-contained test that reproduces your problem:

```
private func badVersion() {
    let center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2, y: view.bounds.height / 2)
    let radius: CGFloat = 100
    let ringWidth: CGFloat = 44

    let ring = CAShapeLayer()
    ring.frame = view.bounds
    ring.fillColor = nil
    ring.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    ring.lineWidth = ringWidth
    let ringPath = CGMutablePath()
    ringPath.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true)
    ringPath.closeSubpath()
    ring.path = ringPath
    view.layer.addSublayer(ring)

    let wedge = CAShapeLayer()
    wedge.frame = view.bounds
    wedge.fillColor = nil
    wedge.strokeColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    wedge.lineWidth = ringWidth
    wedge.lineCap = kCALineCapButt
    let wedgePath = CGMutablePath()
    wedgePath.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0.1, endAngle: 0.6, clockwise: false)
    wedge.path = wedgePath
    view.layer.addSublayer(wedge)
}
```

Here's the part of the screen that shows the problem:

[image: the problem]

One way to fix this is to draw the colors beyond the edges of the ring, and use a mask to clip them to the ring shape.

I'll change my code so that instead of drawing a red ring, and part of a gray ring on top of it, I draw a red disc, and a gray wedge on top of it:

[image: red disc with gray wedge]

If you zoom in, you can see that this still shows the red fringe at the edge of the gray wedge. So the trick is to use a ring-shaped mask to get the final shape. Here's the shape of the mask, drawn in white on top of the prior image:

[image: white mask]

Note that the mask is well away from the problematic area with the fringe. When I use the mask as a mask instead of drawing it, I get the final, perfect result:

[image: perfect ring]

Here's the code that draws the perfect version:

```
private func goodVersion() {
    let center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2, y: view.bounds.height / 2)
    let radius: CGFloat = 100
    let ringWidth: CGFloat = 44
    let slop: CGFloat = 10

    let disc = CAShapeLayer()
    disc.frame = view.bounds
    disc.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    disc.strokeColor = nil
    let ringPath = CGMutablePath()
    ringPath.addArc(center: center, radius: radius + ringWidth / 2 + slop, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true)
    ringPath.closeSubpath()
    disc.path = ringPath
    view.layer.addSublayer(disc)

    let wedge = CAShapeLayer()
    wedge.frame = view.bounds
    wedge.fillColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    wedge.strokeColor = nil
    let wedgePath = CGMutablePath()
    wedgePath.move(to: center)
    wedgePath.addArc(center: center, radius: radius + ringWidth / 2 + slop, startAngle: 0.1, endAngle: 0.6, clockwise: false)
    wedgePath.closeSubpath()
    wedge.path = wedgePath
    view.layer.addSublayer(wedge)

    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.frame = view.bounds
    mask.fillColor = nil
    mask.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    mask.lineWidth = ringWidth
    let maskPath = CGMutablePath()
    maskPath.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true)
    maskPath.closeSubpath()
    mask.path = maskPath
    view.layer.mask = mask
}
```

Note that the mask applies to *everything* in `view`, so (in your case) you may need to move all of your layers into a subview has no other contents so it's safe to mask.

### UPDATE

Looking at your playground, the problem is (still) that you're drawing two shapes that have exactly the same partially-transparent edge on top of each other. You can't do that. The solution is to draw the colored shapes larger, so that they are both completely opaque at the edge of the donut, and then use the layer mask to clip them to the donut shape.

I fixed your playground. Notice how in my version, the `lineWidth` of each colored section is `donutThickness + 10`, and the mask's `lineWidth` is only `donutThickness`. Here's the result:

[image: playground output]

Here's the playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ABDonutChart: UIView {

    struct Datum {
        var value: Double
        var color: UIColor
    }

    var donutThickness: CGFloat = 20 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    var separatorValue: Double = 1 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    var separatorColor: UIColor = .white { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    var data = [Datum]() { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

    func withAnimation(_ wantAnimation: Bool, do body: () -> ()) {
        let priorFlag = wantAnimation
        self.wantAnimation = true
        defer { self.wantAnimation = priorFlag }
        body()
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let bounds = self.bounds
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width / 2, y: bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height / 2)
        let radius = (min(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) - donutThickness) / 2

        let maskLayer = layer.mask as? CAShapeLayer ?? CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = bounds
        maskLayer.fillColor = nil
        maskLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        maskLayer.lineWidth = donutThickness
        maskLayer.path = CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect(x: center.x - radius, y: center.y - radius, width: 2 * radius, height: 2 * radius), transform: nil)
        layer.mask = maskLayer

        var spareLayers = segmentLayers
        segmentLayers.removeAll()

        let finalSum = data.reduce(Double(0)) { $0 + $1.value + separatorValue }
        var runningSum: Double = 0

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = 0.0
        animation.toValue = 1.0
        animation.duration = 2
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

        func addSegmentLayer(color: UIColor, segmentSum: Double) {
            let angleOffset: CGFloat = -0.25 * 2 * .pi

            let segmentLayer = spareLayers.popLast() ?? CAShapeLayer()
            segmentLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
            segmentLayer.lineWidth = donutThickness + 10
            segmentLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapButt
            segmentLayer.fillColor = nil

            let path = CGMutablePath()
            path.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: angleOffset, endAngle: CGFloat(segmentSum / finalSum * 2 * .pi) + angleOffset, clockwise: false)
            segmentLayer.path = path

            layer.insertSublayer(segmentLayer, at: 0)
            segmentLayers.append(segmentLayer)

            if wantAnimation {
                segmentLayer.add(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
            }
        }

        for datum in data {
            addSegmentLayer(color: separatorColor, segmentSum: runningSum + separatorValue / 2)
            runningSum += datum.value + separatorValue
            addSegmentLayer(color: datum.color, segmentSum: runningSum - separatorValue / 2)
        }

        addSegmentLayer(color: separatorColor, segmentSum: finalSum)

        spareLayers.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
    }

    private var segmentLayers = [CAShapeLayer]()
    private var wantAnimation = false
}

let container = UIView()
container.frame.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
container.backgroundColor = .black
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = container
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let m = ABDonutChart(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 215, height: 215))
m.center = CGPoint(x: container.bounds.size.width / 2, y: container.bounds.size.height / 2)
container.addSubview(m)

m.withAnimation(true) {
    m.data = [
        .init(value: 10, color: .red),
        .init(value: 30, color: .blue),
        .init(value: 15, color: .orange),
        .init(value: 40, color: .yellow),
        .init(value: 50, color: .green)]
}
```

Comment: Thats a greatest answer, thanks a lot! One question - in order to avoid fringe outside the ring, i need to have outer mask too(like what you have drawn with black outside) ?

Comment: The black is just the `backgroundColor` of the top-level view.

Comment: in second picture you have outer fringe and in third - no. To accomplish that I have to use outer mask ?

Comment: There are four pictures and the first three all show a fringe. There is exactly one mask, and it's only used as a mask in the fourth picture.

Comment: I tried your code, but it masks only inner edges, outer still have fringe. Can you please take a look at upd?

Comment: There's not enough in your update for me to diagnose the problem. Did you notice that in my `goodVersion`, I add `slop` to the radius of the colored areas so they extend past the edge of the mask?

Comment: yes, but I can't understand the logic :( if I make mask radius bigger - I don't get any result, if I make radius of chart bigger - i still have outer fringe + white border inside chart

Comment: can you please take a look at playgrounds ? https://pastebin.com/fiW5JUFW

Comment: I have looked at your playground and updated my answer.

Comment: Thats the greatest answer I have ever seen on stackoverflow. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like the edges are antialiased resulting in somewhat transparent pixels. The orange of the background can then be seen through the 'blurred' edges of the overlay.
Have you tried making the overlaid layers opaque?

```
layer.Opaque = true; //C#
```

An alternative way may be to draw a thin circle with the background color on top the orange edges. This should work, but it's not the prettiest method.

Comment: opaque doesn't help. the circle can't be drawn also, because there is image in background