# SwiftUI: How to make ZStack embedded components have the same corner radius

Tags: ios, swiftui, mobile

I am having two 200*200 colours stacked in a **ZStack** with exact same corner radius 40. Found **white** is not able to cover **red** under it at four corners. Why is it happening? Any solution?

```
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .cornerRadius(20)
            Color.white.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .cornerRadius(20)
        }
    }
```

Tried to attach cornerRadius on ZStack but same results

Comment: Try moving the `.cornerRadius(20)` onto the `ZStack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're drawing the same partially-transparent shape twice in the same position, and alpha compositing is not designed to handle that. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43638080/77567) for a more in-depth explanation.

Moving the `cornerRadius` modifier onto the `ZStack` doesn't help. `ZStack`  doesn't have its own appearance, so it just passes the modifier down to its children.

You need to tell SwiftUI to apply the corner mask to `ZStack`'s children as a group, not individually. One way to do this is using the `compositingGroup` modifier:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.red.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        Color.white.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
    .compositingGroup()
    .cornerRadius(40)
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution, it worked. Actually tried to attach .compositingGroup() on both Red and White, it didn't work. :/ Making more sense adding it on ZStack